# Using mysql select to put data in another table?

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
use datafeeds;
 select date, speed, dir from weather 
 where date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Which selects this data:

```
date                   speed   dir           
2014-03-23 19:33:00    100     e
2014-03-23 19:38:00    26      se
2014-03-23 19:43:01    37      e
2014-03-23 19:48:01    93      sw
2014-03-23 19:53:01    47      nne
2014-03-23 19:58:01    81      n
2014-03-23 20:03:00    28      s
2014-03-23 20:08:00    12      nw
```

I would like to modify this so that the data for each wind direction is entered into its own table. I need this to create rose diagrams.

So I would have 16 tables, like one called wind_e with (date, speed)
In wind_e

```
date                   speed              
2014-03-23 19:33:00    100     
2014-03-23 19:43:01    37
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to insert to `wind_e` table use this

```
  insert into wind_e (date,speed)
  select date, speed from weather 
  where dir = 'e' 
  AND date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

and same for table `wind_n` and so on for other tables...

Comment: ok thanks. I thought there might be a fancy one liner sql code that might have done the job :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do an insert from select:

Try:

```
use datafeeds;
insert into other_table (date,speed,dir)
 select date, speed, dir from weather 
 where date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: I want to put the data into 16 different tables depending on the wind direction. Could I need to create 16 different statements and use the like for each one to determine what data to put into the table?

Comment: If you have 16 different tables to store the data, u would have to decide which one you want to store at runtime, try using CASE WHEN for this. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html